# Bug with conditional formatting (and personal formula maybe)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

On Excel 2010, I have some spectaculars bugs after a conditional formating :

Before:

[image]

After:

[image] or like that (depends...) : [image]

And without bug it could be like that :

[image]

I'm more or less sure that is an Excel bug caused by my personal formula in VBA:

```
Function NumCol(plage As Range, ch As String) As Long

    'Application.Volatile

    For Each c In plage
        If c.Value = ch Then NumCol = c.Column
    Next

End Function


Function NumLig(plage As Range, ch As String) As Long

    'Application.Volatile

    For Each c In plage
        If c.Value = ch Then NumLig = c.Row
    Next

End Function
```

What can I do to correct this visual bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
c.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 
c.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

in each loop.

Comment: @QuentinT. Is it merged cells?

Comment: Yes, merged cells. Sorry it's my bad, it's working well now (I had missed c.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter...). But I have another bug, when I do an alt+tab on the file, it break again the visual...

Comment: Try add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` on start in your function and add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Comment: And the same with Application.ScreenUpdating true or false... The visual format and bugs appears more or less randomly.